# C# Eval aspx Fun

Tags: c#, asp.net

This works:

```
<asp:Label ID="asdf" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Image1") %>'></asp:Label>
```

displaying data like:  L8_Pic_1.jpg

This doesn't:

```
<asp:Label ID="asdfaf111" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Image1").ToString() %>'></asp:Label>
```

It gives an Object Reference not set to an instance of an object error

I'm aiming to do this:

```
String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("Image1").ToString()) ? "noImage.jpg" : Eval("Image1")
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410942/linq-to-sql-default-value-nullable/3410983#3410983 edited; Convert.ToString() around the Eval() rather than .ToString()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the [null coalesce operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx). It allows you to do just that pattern with `??`:

```
<%# Eval("Image1") ?? "noImage.jpg" %>
```

This evaluates as: if Eval("Image1") is not null, return it, otherwise return "noImage.jpg".